# Laravel grouping routes what is best prefix or middleware

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

When I start thinking grouping my routes and check the documentation. I lost there. There are too many things like prefix, middleware etc.

What is the best way to group routes?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'admin'], function () {})
```

Which approach is best? And why? When to use what approach?

Comment: There is no best approach. Prefixes, middleware, and namespaces are there for different purposes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on their purposes?

Comment: Well, was a silly quesion of mine years ago

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Wait. Prefix and middleware are two different things

`prefix` is a way to Prefix your routes and avoid unnecessary typing e.g:

```
Route::get('post/all','Controller@post');
Route::get('post/user','Controller@post');
```

This can be grouped using prefix `post`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post'], function(){
    Route::get('all','Controller@post');
    Route::get('user','Controller@post');
})
```

In the other hand, Middleware :

> Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the application.

For example using last example now i want the users to be authenticated in my post routes. I can apply a middleware to this group like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
        Route::get('all','Controller@post');
        Route::get('user','Controller@post');
    })
```

You should check the docs to get more informed.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-groups

Comment: It is like a filter. before your request gets to the controller (or after, depends on the middleware type) the middleware handle the request and do things like validations, corrections, etc....

Comment: Cool, how to group all admin routes. Like admin/sales/report, admin/sales/report/edit/1
???

Comment: Cool, how to group all admin routes. Like admin/sales/report, admin/sales/report/edit/1
???

Comment: `'prefix' => 'admin/sales/report'` and inside your routes

Answer (score 12):

**Both are different But to use both at the same time Best technique for grouping route middleware and prefix your route avoid unnecessary typing**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard','AdminController@dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It may not be related to the current question, but if anyone is wondering how to use grouping `prefix` and `middleware` as well as `controller` in a scenario where you need **auth** check and then need a prefix to avoid repeat typing for the specific `controller` group, you may try the following way.

```php
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])
->controller(\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class)
->prefix('dashboard')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/', 'adminIndex')->name('admin.index');
});
```

Or,

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'verified'], 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    Route::controller(\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class)->group(function (){
        Route::get('/', 'adminIndex')->name('admin.index');
    });
});
```